# $First security breach ignore Reader Field

Tags: lotus-domino

[DEDIT] This seems to be due to an agent in the WebQueryOpen of the form... Currently analyzing what really happens.

Is **$First** a known breach in the security? If yes, is there a way to patch it ?

I have a NotesDatabase which ACL is Anonymous Author. I have a view, a document in this view, a form to display this document.

This document has a **reader Field**="[Admin]"   (role admin is NOT given to anonymous)

```
http://myserver/myDdb.nsf/myview/$First
```

Displays the document. When I expect a login to be displayed.

```
http://myserver/myDdb.nsf/myview/universalDocumentID
```

Works correctly and don't display the document until I log in as admin.

Comment: I just did some testing, but it's on a very old server - 7.0.1 (the only version currently available to me for an easy test).  I found that $first did not get around reader security on a document, but I did see an odd effect. I tested on a hierarchical view. When I put a readernames field on the first main doc in the view, the $First argument brought up the first response to the first main doc, even though that doc is not displayed in the view since it's effectively an orphan for anonymous.  So I'm wondering... Is the view you're working with flat, or is it hierarchical or categorized?

Comment: I'm analyzing the problem this is due to the queryopen of the form that run an agent. with a standard form the bug is NOT reproducible.

Comment: Is the agent set to run with the rights of the signer, on behalf of someone, or with the rights of the web user?  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SETTING_UP_AGENT_SECURITY_USING_THE_SECURITY_TAB_OVER.html